# Image segmentation using K-means with texture analysis and (x,y)-coordinates

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, scikit-learn, k-means

I'm trying to implement a color/image segmentation using K-means in Python based on the example of MathWorks:

https://nl.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imsegkmeans.html

Using the (R,G,B)-values as feature set I get the following result:

[image]

However, if we add texture information (using Gabor filters) and pixel location information (x,y) to the featureset this can be improved.

The result:

[image]

For this result I'm not using the (R,G,B)-values because the dog has approximately the same color as the tiles. I'm using the grayscale image, 24 Gabor filters extended with the pixel coordinates.

Unfortunately, the result is not as good as these from Mathworks:

[image: https://nl.mathworks.com/help/examples/images/win64/ImproveKMeansSegmentationExample_05.png]

The goal is to seperate the background from the object using color/texture segmentation.

Do you have an idea to improve this? Thank you very much!

```py
# Based on https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imsegkmeans.html

import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn import preprocessing

# Building some gabor kernels to filter image
orientations = [0.0, np.pi / 2, np.pi, 3 * np.pi / 2]
wavelengths = [3, 6, 12, 24, 48, 96]

def build_gabor_kernels():
    filters = []
    ksize = 40
    for rotation in orientations:
        for wavelength in wavelengths:
            kernel = cv.getGaborKernel((ksize, ksize), 4.25, rotation, wavelength, 0.5, 0, ktype=cv.CV_32F)
            filters.append(kernel)

    return filters

image = cv.imread('./kobi.png')
rows, cols, channels = image.shape

# Resizing the image. 
# Full image is taking to much time to process
image = cv.resize(image, (int(cols * 0.5), int(rows * 0.5)))
rows, cols, channels = image.shape

gray = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

gaborKernels = build_gabor_kernels()

gaborFilters = []

for (i, kernel) in enumerate(gaborKernels):
    filteredImage = cv.filter2D(gray, cv.CV_8UC1, kernel)

    # Blurring the image
    sigma = int(3*0.5*wavelengths[i % len(wavelengths)])

    # Sigma needs to be odd
    if sigma % 2 == 0:
        sigma = sigma + 1

    blurredImage = cv.GaussianBlur(filteredImage,(int(sigma),int(sigma)),0)
    gaborFilters.append(blurredImage)


# numberOfFeatures = 1 (gray color) + number of gabor filters + 2 (x and y)
numberOfFeatures = 1  + len(gaborKernels) + 2

# Empty array that will contain all feature vectors
featureVectors = []

for i in range(0, rows, 1):
    for j in range(0, cols, 1):
        vector = [gray[i][j]]

        for k in range(0, len(gaborKernels)):
            vector.append(gaborFilters[k][i][j])

        vector.extend([i+1, j+1])

        featureVectors.append(vector)

# Some example results:
# featureVectors[0] = [164, 3, 10, 255, 249, 253, 249, 2, 43, 255, 249, 253, 249, 3, 10, 255, 249, 253, 249, 2, 43, 255, 249, 253, 249, 1, 1]
# featureVectors[1] = [163, 3, 17, 255, 249, 253, 249, 2, 43, 255, 249, 253, 249, 3, 17, 255, 249, 253, 249, 2, 43, 255, 249, 253, 249, 1, 2]

# Normalizing the feature vectors
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()

scaler.fit(featureVectors)
featureVectors = scaler.transform(featureVectors)

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=170)
kmeans.fit(featureVectors)

centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_
labels = kmeans.labels_

result = centers[labels]

# Only keep first 3 columns to make it easy to plot as an RGB image
result = np.delete(result, range(3, numberOfFeatures), 1)

plt.figure(figsize = (15,8))
plt.imsave('test.jpg', result.reshape(rows, cols, 3) * 100)
```

Comment: Hi Cris, not exactly. I'm trying to implement the Matlab example in Python without the Matlab functions, but using OpenCV instead. Their example is working correctly.

Comment: I didn’t pay attention to the tags or your code before commenting. :/

Answer (score 0):

The method on Mathworks contains some ad hoc steps. There are much better algorithms available for this problem. First, Gabor filter response alone doesn't give features that are consistent over the same texture region. A better method is to add another step -- computing local histogram over filter response. Use multiple filters and concatenate histograms together. By selecting proper filters, such features can differentiate various texture appearance and be consistent over the same texture region. It is called spectral histograms.

In order to capture meaningful texture appearance, local histogram needs to be computed from relatively large local windows. But when a local window crosses region borders, the features are not reliable. Applying simple grouping methods like k-means with such features leads to bad results near region borders. This [approach](https://sites.google.com/site/factorizationsegmentation/) gives a simple and effective solution. It uses local spectral histograms as features and uses matrix factorization to get segment labels, where boundary can be well localized. It uses mostly matrix operations and therefore is fast. Both matlab and python code are available.